# Cannot get data from interfaces group of MIB-II using snmp queries in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, interface, virtualbox, snmp

Two machines running Ubuntu. One is running on Virtualbox inside the other.

Using the following command **in the VM** (get number of interfaces):

```
snmpget -v 2c -c public localhost 1.3.6.1.2.1.2.1.0
```

I get the following result:

```
iso.3.6.1.2.1.2.1.0 = INTEGER: 2
```

But, if I do it **in the host** (query to the VM):

```
snmpget -v 2c -c public 10.1.14 1.3.6.1.2.1.2.1.0
```

I get:

```
iso.3.6.1.2.1.2.1.0 = No Such Object available on this agent at this OID
```

I can do SNMP queries to objects of System Group, but cannot do SNMP queries to objects of Interfaces Group.

The machine is running Ubuntu 12.10 and the VM is running Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because the /etc/cups/snmp.conf problem ,different Linux has the problem with the snmp.conf,more new Linux ,more problem maybe you will have,you can copy this

```
    com2sec notConfigUser  127.0.0.1       public
    group   notConfigGroup v1           notConfigUser
    group   notConfigGroup v2c           notConfigUser
    view    systemview    included   .1.3.6.1.2.1.1
    view    systemview    included   .1.3.6.1.2.1.25.1.1
    access  notConfigGroup ""      any       noauth    exact  all none none
    view all    included  .1                               80
```

to your /etc/cups/snmp.conf ,I have the problem before,and solved this problem by this way.

Answer (score 0):

to get the snmp interface oid value 
add the following in /etc/snmp/snmpd.conf

view   systemonly  included   .1.3.6.1.2.1.1